# add textview programmatically till the screen becomes full

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want Add TextView Programmaially to the end Of Layout, i use following code to add textview:

```
             final TextView valueTV = new TextView(getActivity());
             valueTV.setText(UrbanLaw.MainCatalog.get(i));
             valueTV.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 0);
             valueTV.setId(Integer.parseInt(getArguments().getString("pageIndex"))*100+ i); 
             ((LinearLayout) layout).addView(valueTV);
```

then i want to get height of each textview and layout to make better view in every android device. i use following code to get height and width:

```
    ViewTreeObserver entire = view.getViewTreeObserver();

    entire.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Log.d( getArguments().getString("pageIndex")+" " +view.getWidth() + " x " + view.getHeight(),"width and height");
             viewHeight = view.getHeight();
             Log.d("view height in method", String.valueOf(viewHeight));
             view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

in the ongloballayout() viewheight is true but when i want use this in out is equal 0. how can solve my problem. Main my question is i want to add text to my layout to end of my layout that sum of textview height less than view height.

//////////////////////////////////////////////
UPDATE:
i want something like this:

```
       while( sumHeight < viewHeight)
       { 
         add (textview)
         sumHeight += textHeight
       }
```

Comment: Multiple means how many?? Is it static number or dynamic??

Comment: its depend on screen device,

Comment: Means till the screen becomes full

Comment: So what are you getting now from this code??

Comment: i want get height of view screen, then before adding textview,get height of that and sum with sumHeight and check that if (sumHeight < viewHeight) then add textview

Comment: So you can get height of screen using getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()

Comment: yes, i can do that with my code too, my problem is height of textview, because the height of textview is equal 0 before starting activity

Comment: Then set height of textview so it will be fixed

Comment: i dont know height of textview,because some of my text is one line and some is 2 line and soon

Comment: Get height after the values is set in textview

Comment: i want but its 0. i use below code:
ViewTreeObserver vto = valueTV.getViewTreeObserver(); 
              
              
              vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
               
                     @Override
               public void onGlobalLayout() { 
//                height123 = valueTV.getHeight();
                UrbanLaw.height += valueTV.getMeasuredHeight();

Comment: Try this valueTV.getLineHeight();

Comment: not working, when i get value from log is right but i think after activity is going up is calculate so not working

Comment: Then store  it somewhere

Comment: i store but after layout is come up i know that, so is not usefull, i think that i mus set height fix, thank you for your answers,very helpfull

Answer (score 2):

Try giving your TextView some layout params:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
valueTV.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Also, if you're trying to get the view's height, you've got a mistake in your code:

```
viewHeight = view.getHeight(); // not getWidth()
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes you right i edit my post, but my main problem is that i want to add multiple textview in layout to end of page